# Linux from scratch's bash problem: $() syntax error

Tags: linux, lfs

When I try to build the glibc following the Linux from scratch instruction Chapter 6.9. Glibc-2.14.1, I get a syntax error about `$(command)`.

The simplified problem is that I can type

```
echo `ls`
```

and get the expected result.
However when I type

```
echo $(ls)
```

which should do the same thing, but I get

```
**bash: command substitution: line 78: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 78: `ls)'**
```

I don't know why the bash program that I created following the instruction of Linux from scratch cannot handle `$()` correctly.

The glibc problem is [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.support/33496).

Any idea?

Comment: It is pretty difficult to know what you are doing. Which shell is executing the command? How did you install it? (And please link the instructions you are using)

Comment: You're comparing interactive mode `that I can type` with a script `line 78`. What do you get when you type both. What, if you use backticks in the script? I can use both interactively.

Comment: Line 78? I don't see any line 78 here. We can't answer your question if you don't give us all the data. If you're running on a command line, post the full transcript of your session. If you're executing a script, post the whole script.

Comment: @Gilles. I just type the command echo $(ls) on a command line, and the bash tell me syntax error near unexpected token `)'. The bash I use is built following the instruction of [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.0/chapter05/bash.html).In fact the original problem is [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.support/33496), as Oz Gonaz stated. You may tell me how to solve this original problem instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to build bash with a better bison (yacc) on your host. Bash uses yacc grammar rules and only GNU bison will generate the correct parsing code for the Bash build.

Comment: djerome's answer is right. compile bash need yacc which in bison you need exec version-check.sh before all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure quotes, parentheses and any other grouping structures are nested properly within your script. This error is a typical result of such issues.

Comment: I just type echo $(ls) on a command line, the bash tells me syntax error. I think this command is nested properly. @l0b0

Comment: Can you post any relevant `env` contents, such as `$SHELL`?

Comment: `TERM=xterm
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin
PWD=/
PS1=\u:\w\$ 
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
_=/tools/bin/env
`@l0b0

Comment: `SHLVL=2` is interesting - It means you're running a shell within another shell. But is there no `$SHELL` or similar variable? It should be set by most shells.